# Unity3d - Create new gameobject from existing objects in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am beginner in Unity3d. i would like to ask you about creating new gameobject from exsiting objects in unity3d.

I want to to create new gameobject from existing spheres and squares in unity3d. Right now, i only drag them to become a group. In addition, I want spheres and squares in the new gameobject not to effect collider together.

The new object only collide with other outside objects. How i can do it?

More a question, i would like to create a hoop object in Unity3D, Has already hoop object existed in Unity3D? It has not existed yet, please tell me how to create it? and the space is at middle of hoop not to effect collider ??? Thanks so much,

If my question is not easy to understand, i will edit.

Comment: You lost me at spheres and squares... Are you talking 2d or 3d? Can you post a picture of what you are talking about because I could not understand any of that

Comment: I am talking about 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're after a [Prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html).

Once you've created your prefab, you might want to [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html) it.

To avoid collisions, make sure your prefab does not have a Collider component. Simply remove the component inside the prefab.

A hoop shape is also known as a taurus or a donut. This isn't available as a primitive in Unity3D but it is very easily created in 3D modelling programs and used within Unity3D's mesh import.

Answer (score 0):

1. As Nathan pointed out, create a prefab from your objects.
2. It looks like you want your objects to act like a compound collider (see Compound Colliders section [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Rigidbody.html)). You need your objects to have Collider components, and you need to add RigidBody component to their parent GameObject.
3. About torus collider: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/27906-Adding-a-new-collider-primitive